# ImageDownloader not retrieving image from storage in android 4.0

Tags: android

Below is the code for imagedownloader which I am using. When a particular image is downloaded first time imagedownloader will download it and store it. For future references again I will pass the url. If image exists then it will be retrieved locally and if it does not exist it will be downloaded. This code functions properly in android 2.2 and 2.3.3. However when i ran it in emulator: android 4.0 and my note2 the image is always downloaded from the internet. It is not retrieved from local storage.

```
    ImageDownloader.java
    public class ImageDownloader {

    Map<String,Bitmap> imageCache;

    public ImageDownloader(){
        imageCache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    }

    //download function
    public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
         if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {

             //Caching code right here
             String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
             File f = new File(getCacheDirectory(imageView.getContext()), filename);

              // Is the bitmap in our memory cache?
             Bitmap bitmap = null;

              bitmap = (Bitmap)imageCache.get(f.getPath());

              if(bitmap == null){

                  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());

                  if(bitmap != null){
                      imageCache.put(f.getPath(), bitmap);
                  }

              }
              //No? download it
              if(bitmap == null){
                  BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                  DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                  imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                  task.execute(url);
              }else{
                  //Yes? set the image
                  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              }
         }
    }

    //cancel a download (internal only)
    private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

        if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
            String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
            if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
                bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                // The same URL is already being downloaded.
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //gets an existing download if one exists for the imageview
    private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageView != null) {
            Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
                DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable)drawable;
                return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //our caching functions
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    private static File getCacheDirectory(Context context){
        String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        File cacheDir;

        if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  

            //TODO : Change your diretcory here
            cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data/tac/images");
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from ");
        }
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
            return cacheDir;
    }

    private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
          FileOutputStream out = null;

          try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally { 
            try { if (out != null ) out.close(); }
            catch(Exception ex) {} 
          }
    }
    ///////////////////////

    //download asynctask
    public class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private String url;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        // Actual download method, run in the task thread
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
             // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
             url = (String)params[0];
             return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                // Change bitmap only if this process is still associated with it
                if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    //cache the image


                    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
                    File f = new File(getCacheDirectory(imageView.getContext()), filename);

                    imageCache.put(f.getPath(), bitmap);

                    writeFile(bitmap, f);
                }
            }
        }


    }

    static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

        public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
            super(Color.BLACK);
            bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
                new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
        }

        public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
            return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
        }
    }

    //the actual download code
    static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();  
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                //client.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ShutterBug Library to download pic from HTTP.

https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug

It just a one line code.

Thanks